# My Ubuntu suddenly won't boot-- How can I access my files to do a reload without losing most of my data?

Tags: data-recovery

I am able to access the /home dir on the drive after  I mount and decrypt but I cannot access certain folders in the user directory.

I get a permissions error

running 14.04.3

Comment: Could you add a `ls -al /home/username` as an [edit] to your question?

Comment: Is this your user directory or other users directories? Have you tried as super user?

Answer (score 0):

If you still have access to your Ubuntu install CD/Live USB, reboot and start up the installer. From there you can use the file browser to recover your files, then reinstall.